# How to resolve mongodb pool destroyed error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have connected mongodb using mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, (err) => { 
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.'); } else { console.log('Error in MongoDB connection : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
});
```

After rebooted my system I am facing below the issues.

I am not able to connect mongodb. If i start using mongod command i am getting this error:

```
***aborting after fassert() failure 
    2020-07-06T15:31:16.058+0530 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread] Got signal: 22 (SIGABRT).
    mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace_windows.cpp(246)                                                                       mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
    mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(241)                                                              mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0x81
    ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       raise+0x1dd
    ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       abort+0x31
    mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(145)                                                                              mongo::fassertFailedWithLocation+0xd6
```

Also i am not able to use anything like find,save ect..mongoose query.If i do anything i am getting below error

```
MongoError: pool destroyed
        at Pool.write (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:840:8)
        at _command (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\wireprotocol\command.js:128:10)
        at command (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\wireprotocol\command.js:28:5)
        at Object.query (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\wireprotocol\query.js:57:3)
        at Server.query (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:644:16)
        at FindOperation.execute (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\find.js:24:12)
        at D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:151:17
        at Server.selectServer (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:832:3)
        at Server.selectServer (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\topology_base.js:342:32)
        at executeWithServerSelection (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:137:12)
        at executeOperation (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:75:7)
        at Cursor._initializeCursor (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\cursor.js:536:7)
        at Cursor._initializeCursor (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:185:11)
        at nextFunction (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\cursor.js:739:10)
        at Cursor._next (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\cursor.js:202:5)
        at fetchDocs (D:\Projects\Angular\project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:833:16) {
      [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
    }
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Do you have mongo server up and running? Can you connect to it via mongo shell? How are you connecting to the server in your code? Please update your question.

Comment: @noam: I rebooted my system then only i am facing like this issue

Comment: @noam: Need to delete this file? mongod.lock

Comment: Maybe you have a mongoose `db.disconnect()` or `mongoose.connection.close();` somewhere in your code that is run before you're actually done?

Comment: I did not use db.disconnect() or mongoose.connection.close(); in my code